# Saving user settings in objective c

Tags: objective-c, settings

I am developing an app where I want the user to be able to customize certain aspects of the app experience.  I plan on providing a settings screen where they can toggle some options.  What is the best way to save this data and have it persist between the app closing, phone resets, etc?

I know that I can do this with default settings, but that seems a little clunky . . . is there a better way?

Comment: What's clunky about using `NSUserDefaults`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is for user preferences, usually basic objects like `NSString` or `NSNumber`.

`Sqlite`, serializing a collection of objects in a property list, or `Core Data` are all valid options for storing user data such as model objects you created.

You're not going to see a speed difference, but it's still best to pick the correct mechanism for what you're doing. If it's just preferences then use `NSUserDefaults`, otherwise I would serialize your objects to a `plist`.

If you're new to Cocoa I would avoid `Core Data` and even `sqlite` at first, to give yourself a chance to learn the basics first.